# Sleeping bus laws in Europe?

Tags: legal, safety, buses, sleeping

We are working on a project to set up a sleeping bus service within some European countries and between different European cities. But we are not sure about national laws related to safety belt regulations and whether it is possible or not to sleep in a sort of capsule bed in buses while riding.

Your collaboration would be a great help.

Thank you all!

Comment: If you are not sure, then hire a lawyer who will do the job. You wouldn't trust some random people on the internet in such a thing, would you?

Comment: I am sorry, I might have not explained well. It is an academic project for a state university. We need it to be as real as possible @Neusser. And pelase notice we are focusing our project in EUROPE.

Comment: I'm not affiliated with them or a lawyer but these people seem to have managed it. https://www.travelbyknight.co.uk

Comment: If doing this as an academic project, I would include a list of activities that need to be done but require some funding. Consulting lawyers and bus safety experts goes on that list.

Comment: Depending on how you count it, Europe has about 50 different countries with 50 different legislation. You may want to constrain the scope a bit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not affect the traveller but the business conducting the travel. This site is one for the travellers themselves to ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

Start-up projects have at least three major phases. During the first phase, there is no funding, just people who know each other talking and writing. During the second phase, they have obtained some money. It may have come from their own savings or been borrowed. In the third phase, they have actual financing sufficient to pay salaries etc., and it is a business.

You can only really emulate the first phase - you are not expected to sink your savings or commit to debt for an academic projects.

Consulting lawyers is going to cost some money. How much will depend on which countries you are considering operating in and whether there are e.g. common EU regulations or separate national regulations. During the first phase, the phase you can emulate, one of the objectives is to prepare a list of activities to do before starting the business but that are going to cost money. Your aim should be a really good list of questions for the lawyers.